# xml creation from php scipt not working

Tags: php, xml

i am trying to create a page of xml from php

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load("recv.xml") or exit("not loaded");
$xml_album = $xml->createElement("Album");
$xml_track = $xml->createElement("Track");
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );
$xml->appendChild( $xml_album );
$doc->save('recv.xml');
```

this is my script but it is not working 
Do i need to include to any file. Help me

Edit, error description according to comment;

```
DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]:
Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Comment: "Not working" is not enough to go on, what error messages do you get?

Comment: DOMDocument::load() [function.DOMDocument-load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: Looks like your `recv.xml` contains malformed XML.

Comment: Post the content of the file recv.xml

Comment: recv.xml doesnt have any content <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> just this much

Comment: XML document must at least have one node - THE ROOT NODE

Comment: then can you tell me how to create a root node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create a fresh new document instead of loading existing not properly formed document.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
//$xml->load("recv.xml") or exit("not loaded"); - do not load the existing document!!!!
$xml_album = $xml->createElement("Album");
$xml_track = $xml->createElement("Track");
$xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );
$xml->appendChild( $xml_album );
$xml->save('recv.xml');
```

XML is not allowed to have more than one root node, so if you are using `<Album>` as a root, opening existing document and adding one more root node will also produce error.

Comment: $xml = new DOMDocument();
 $xml_album = $xml->createElement("Album");
 $xml_track = $xml->createElement("Track");
 $xml_album->appendChild( $xml_track );
 $xml->appendChild( $xml_album );
  $doc->save('recv1.xml');but still it doesnt work........no recv1.xml is created

Comment: you use variable `$doc`, instead of `$xml` --> $doc->save(...) and it should be $xml->save(...)